# Search ranking challenge

Tags: search

The search ranking built into Craft orders site content searches by score...but that compromises the "exact match" searches that users might make for significant page titles that don't get searched for as often, but contain key words that are often searched. Is there a way around this? to allow the user to set the search by "exact match"? or to set the site to pick one or the other as its standard?

thanks,
Karin

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I'm following the question 100%, but if you want to search for an "exact match" you can use put your search term in quotes.  i.e. `"search for this exact phrase"`.  And if you want to find an exact match in a particular field, you can use `fieldHandle:"exact match"`.

You can see the full search syntax list here: https://craftcms.com/docs/searching